# Deploy Community Builder audience page assignments with ant migration tool?

Tags: ant, community-builder, audience, page-variation

In Community Builder, if you create audiences and assign them to page variations, you cannot deploy these using change sets, according to [Considerations for Deploying Communities with Change Sets](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_migrate_considerations.htm&type=5).  In fact, Audience doesn't even appear in the list of change set components.

On the other hand, Audience metadata can be deployed using the ant migration tool, so I was hopeful that the audience assignments would also be deployable.

Unfortunately, I haven't had success in deploying any audience assignments, either for entire pages or for components on a page.  Has anyone found a workaround for deploying audience assignments for Community Builder pages?  I should say that I'm using the Build Your Own template.

If it can't be deployed, is there at least a way to get a list of audience assignments so I don't have to open every single page in the Community Builder to check?

Here's what I'm using in my package.xml manifest.  All the community builder page variations and all the audiences are created correctly, but the assignments are not.

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>Audience</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>CustomSite</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>SiteDotCom</name>
</types>
```

Comment: just to clarify, you mean a page variation with its assigned audience?

Comment: Yes, a page variation with its assigned audience, but also an assigned component within a page. I've edited my post to include that.

Comment: @DavidCheng did you manage to deploy audiences with their assignments? I've found that assignment can be found in Audience xml file, under <target> tag as it is here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_audience.htm

Unfortunately, I can't retrieve this target and I'm wondering if someone has successfully deployed audiences with assignments.

Comment: @jm.No I had to recreate all the assignments manually.

Comment: did you try experience bundle https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/communities_dev_migrate_expbundle.htm

Comment: @sdandamud1 I didn't know about this, I'll try it for my next deployment, thanks.

Comment: @DavidCheng did Expirience Bundle solved your issue? Can it be used to deploy Audiences and other community components? Thanks

Comment: @EnrikHysko I haven't had another deployment to test with since then.

Answer (score 1):

@DavidCheng, @EnrikHysko, just wanted to share my findings. ExperienceBundle does not help with audience assignments. But with metadata api (ant deployment) the audience and assignments can be migrated. The 'Audience' metadata type in the package.xml works.

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>Audience</name>
</types>
```

The target tag in the retrieved components have the assignment related details and gets deployed to the target environment. Hope this helps.

Comment: Please include an example of the package.xml for the Audience metadata type.

Comment: @DaveHumm, added the example package.xml in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to this old thread for posterity because by golly, this one is esoteric.

The priority of an Audience is in the definition of the Audience (in audience/) in the `targets` node.

```
<target>
    <groupName>3e398530-ec64-4c56-8ff7-afa8ab3343ad</groupName>
    <priority>5</priority>
    <targetType>ExperienceVariation</targetType>
    <targetValue>Search_2023_Search_French_Belgium_Page</targetValue>
</target>
```

The `groupName` corresponds to the ID of the `route` in the `ExperienceBundle`. "Group" here is the common parent ID of the Page Variations. So the node above indicates that within group `3e398530-ec64-4c56-8ff7-afa8ab3343ad`, the variation `Search_2023_Search_French_Belgium_Page` is priority 5.
[image]

Additionally, the `targetValue` will tie to the `developerName` node of the relevant variation in the `ExperienceBundle`.

There is also a table that you can query with ordinary SOQL called `PersonalizationTargetInfo`. This ties the Variation to the Group again, plus the `ContainerId` (your Community's `Network` ID) and a draft status. The exact purpose of this table ... I'm not sure.